# Bulk Insert Includes Line Terminator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am bulk importing data from a pipe-separated CSV file into SQL Server.  The data is formatted like

A|B|CCCCCC\r\n

I have validated both that the file is in UTF-8 format and that lines are terminated with "\r\n" by viewing the CSV file in a hex editor.

The command is

```
BULK INSERT MyTable FROM 'C:\Path\File.csv'
WITH (FIRSTROW=1, MAXERRORS=0, BATCHSIZE=10000, FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', 
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n')
```

The third column originally was defined as CHAR(6) as this field is always a code exactly 6 (ASCII) characters wide.  That resulted in a truncation error during bulk insert.

I then widened the column to CHAR(8).  The import worked, but

```
SELECT CAST(Col3 As VARBINARY(MAX))
```

indicates that the column data ends with 0x0D0A (or "\r\n", the row terminator)

Why is the row terminator being included in the imported data and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, SQL Server doesn't support UTF-8 and you just need `\n` as the row terminator.

It's actually a bit unclear what's going on because you didn't provide the table definition or the precise error messages. Having said all that, I could load the following data:

```
create table dbo.BCPTest (
    col1 nchar(1) not null,
    col2 nchar(1) not null,
    col3 nchar(6) not null
)

/* This data can saved as ASCII, UTF-16 with BOM or UTF-8 without BOM
   (see comments below)

A|B|CCCCCC
D|E|FFFFFF

*/

BULK INSERT dbo.BCPTest FROM 'c:\testfile.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

Comments:

- When I created and saved a in Notepad as "UTF-8", it added the BOM bytes 0xEFBBBF which is the standard [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
- But, SQL Server [doesn't support UTF-8, it supports UTF-16](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikosan/archive/2011/12/29/sql-server-and-utf-8-encoding-1-true-or-false.aspx) (offical docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx#Unicode_Defn)) and it [expects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188289.aspx) a BOM of 0xFFFE
- So I saved the file again in Notepad as "Unicode", and it added the 0xFFFE BOM; this loaded fine as shown above. Out of curiosity I also saved it (using Notepad++) as "UTF-8 without BOM" and I could load that file too
- Saving the file as ASCII also loads fine with the same table data types and `BULK INSERT` command
- The row terminator should be `\n` not `\r\n` because `\n` is [interpreted as a "newline"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191485.aspx), i.e. SQL Server (and/or Windows) is being 'clever' by interpreting `\n` semantically instead of literally. This is most likely a result of the [C handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages) of `\r` and `\n`, which doesn't require them to be interpreted literally.